# action mailer for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have been following quite an old tutorial in order to create a contact form and then create a mailer that sends to the site admin. I am running into some problems i think because i am on rails 4.1.1 and the tutorial is so old! I was wondering if anyone could give me some guidance-i am learning rails. The error i am currently getting is  NoMethodError in MessagesController#create undefined method `subject' for #
  subject    message.subject

here is my code

messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /messages
  # GET /messages.json
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  # GET /messages/1
  # GET /messages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # GET /messages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /messages
  # POST /messages.json
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
    ContactMailer.deliver_message(@message)
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

# PATCH/PUT /messages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.update(message_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

# DELETE /messages/1
  # DELETE /messages/1.json
  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :company, :phone, :subject, :body)
end
```

end

development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smpt.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: 'your_email_username',
    password: 'your_email_password'
  }

  CONTACT_RECIPIENT = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Required for Devise gem
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

end

class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.contact_mailer.message.subject
  #

    def message(message)
    subject    message.subject
    body       :message => message
    recipients CONTACT_RECIPIENT
    from       message.email
    sent_on    Time.now
    end

  end
end
```

message.html.erb

```
Email from your web site

From: <%= @message.name %>

Company: <%= @message.company %>

Phone: <%= @message.phone %>

Message: <%= @message.body %>
```

messages/_form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :company %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :subject %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

the relevant part of the db schema file

```
 create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "company"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Did you put your `ContactMailer` class inside of `development.rb`? Perhaps taking a look at [ActionMailer basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) will help as well.

Comment: Is subject a column on the messages table? you can double check your db/schema.rb to verify that it is listed under the messages table. Also, what Justin said.. your ContactMailer should be in app/mailers, not in development.rb

Comment: i believe the subject column is there-i have edited the question accordingly!

Comment: when you say put contact mailer inside of development.rb file could you expand a bit. I have already exhausted all the docs i can find including that before i asked on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def deliver_message(message)
  subject    message.subject
  body       :message => message
  recipients CONTACT_RECIPIENT
  from       message.email
  sent_on    Time.now
end
```

should be

```
def deliver_message(message)
  @message = message
  mail(subject: message.subject, body: message.body, recipients: CONTACT_RECIPIENT, from: message.email, sent_on: Time.now)
 end
```

Comment: SyntaxError (/Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    subject:    message.subject
            ^
/Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    body:       :message => message
         ^
/Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    recipients: CONTACT_RECIPIENT
               ^
/Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    from:       message.email
         ^

Comment: /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    sent_on:    Time.now
            ^
/Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input):

Comment: /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end subject: message.subject, ^ /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' body: message.body, ^ /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' recipients: CONTACT_RECIPIENT, ^ /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:28: dynamic constant assignment /Users/em/new/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' sent_on: Time.now ^